# Javascript Variable Can't Pass Into Textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a script that pulls data from a form when it's submitted and passes that data to the next page.

On that page it displays the text...

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name")</script>
```

So it prints the name that the user gave earlier.

So I tried putting that into a textbox to pre-populate it....

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name")</script>" />
```

Unfortunately it just shows the code rather than the actual name.

So is there an easy way for me to get the text that displays with

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name")</script>
```

and put that into a textbox?

Comment: add a fiddle that will be helpful.

Comment: Please re edit your question; Make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not work that way...

Add an id to the input html:

```
<input id="myInputBox" class="text" type="text" name="name" value="" />
```

Just do this javascript onLoad:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myInputBox");
elem.value = "My value";
```

Check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ve65v/

Answer (score 0):

Hi its hard way you are trying to achieve. One way is how @Trader provided other is to use templates and call it through JS. Following is [fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/djYzd/). Hope it will be helpful

```
// HTML
<script id="template">
    <input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="{{user}}" />
</script>

<div id="render"></div>

// JS
var user = "Anil"
var template = $("#template").html()
template = template.replace("{{user}}", user)

$("#render").html(template)
```